# Comparing and Sorting Values Between Columns in Python (with "Not Matched" Column)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Question:**
I'm working on a Python project where I have a dataset with two columns: "Big List" and "Small List". My goal is to compare the values in the "Small List" column with the values in the "Big List" column and sort them accordingly. If a value from the "Small List" column is found in the "Big List" column, I want to sort the corresponding row in the "Small List" column. Additionally, if a value from the "Small List" column is not found in the "Big List" column, I want to list it in a new column named "Not Matched to Big List".

The values in the "Big List" are not unique, but the values in the "Small List" are unique.

Here's an example:

| Big List | Small List |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 15 | 42 |
| 17 | 31 |
| 30 | 45 |
| 40 | 30 |
| 45 |  |
| 47 |  |
| 50 |  |

In this case, I want to compare each value in the "Small List" column with the values in the "Big List" column. If a match is found, I want to sort the corresponding row in the "Small List" column. If a match is not found, I want to list the value in the "Not Matched to Big List" column.

Expected result:

| Big List | Small List | Not Matched to Big List |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 |  | 31 |
| 2 |  | 42 |
| 15 | 15 |  |
| 17 | 17 |  |
| 30 | 30 |  |
| 40 |  |  |
| 45 | 45 |  |
| 47 |  |  |
| 50 |  |  |

I'm struggling with how to sort the row in the "Small List" column when a match is found and how to populate the "Not Matched to Big List" column when there's no match. Any help or suggestions on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated!

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Big List': [10,2,15,17,30,40,45,47,50], 'Small List': [17,15,42,31,45,30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Loop through rows and compare values
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Small List'] in df['Big List']:
        # Sort the row in the "Small List" column
        # Stuck here
    else:
        # Add value to "Not Matched to Big List" column
        # Stuck here

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (although I must add that this solution is quite cumbersome as Pandas dataframe should express relations between the different columns and what is done here has none):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Big List': [10,2,15,17,30,40,45,47,50], 'Small List': [17,15,42,31,45,30, None, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = df[['Big List']].merge(df[['Small List']], left_on='Big List', right_on='Small List', how='left')
new_df.sort_values(by='Big List', inplace=True)
notfound_df = df[['Big List']].merge(df[['Small List']], left_on='Big List', right_on='Small List', how='right')
notfound_df = notfound_df[notfound_df['Big List'].isna()].dropna(how='all')
notfound_list = notfound_df['Small List'].to_list()
for i in range(new_df.shape[0] - len(notfound_list)):
    notfound_list.append(None)
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.DataFrame(notfound_list, columns=['Not Matched to Big List'])], axis=1)
new_df

   Big List  Small List  Not Matched to Big List
1         2         NaN                     31.0
0        10         NaN                     42.0
2        15        15.0                      NaN
3        17        17.0                      NaN
4        30        30.0                      NaN
5        40         NaN                      NaN
6        45        45.0                      NaN
7        47         NaN                      NaN
8        50         NaN                      NaN
```

Comment: How can I fill the empty cells in the "Small List" with "None"?

Comment: With which values would you like to fill it with?

Comment: i did it .... but tank you very much for your support

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.Series(
            np.sort(
                df.loc[~df["Small List"].isin(df["Big List"]), "Small List"]
                .dropna()
                .values
            ),
            name="Not Matched to Big List",
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

df["Small List"] = df.loc[df["Big List"].isin(df["Small List"]), "Big List"]

print(df.replace(np.nan, None))
```

Prints:

```
   Big List Small List Not Matched to Big List
0        10       None                    31.0
1         2       None                    42.0
2        15       15.0                    None
3        17       17.0                    None
4        30       30.0                    None
5        40       None                    None
6        45       45.0                    None
7        47       None                    None
8        50       None                    None
```